# ImageView inside CardView with rounded corners is drawn incorrectly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, imageview, cardview

There is a CardView with an ImageView inside. CardView has 50dp corner radius to crop the ImageView inside it as a circle. However, in some devices, the ImageView inside is rendered in a weird way.

Desired output which I achieved in most devices:
[image: Desired output]

Yet, on some devices, it is rendered in such a strange way:
[image: Problematic output]

For the record, I already started to use another method for circle ImageViews, however, I would like to know why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, if ImageView is directly placed in CardView, the placed image does not have match_parent. You need to nest a layer of RelativeLayout on top of ImageView.